# How can I copy text from bootstrap tool-tip in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my current project, I have some tables where the text of some column doesn't fit, so I fixed the width of the column and using the bootstrap tooltip to show the full table data where the column doesn't fit. Now I want to copy the tooltip data.

Comment: You should give us some of your code to understand the problem a bit better. And explain on your code the problem that we can test it.

Comment: Bootstrap tooltip reads from the title attribute of an element, you need to read this.